# Deploy Service Fabric through Azure DevOps and manage environment variables in Octopus

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, octopus-deploy

I have a Service Fabric CI/CD in Azure DevOps working fine. Now I want to be able to manage and separate my variables by environment, and someone pointed out Octopus like this:

[image: Octopus Dashboard]

I'm a bit lost with this. Should I install the Octopus extension in Azure DevOps to be able to manage my variables in there while keeping my existing Azure DevOps CI/CD pipelines, or do I need to ditch Azure DevOps and do an entirely new thing in Octopus?
Would someone have a detailed explanation of what I need to do in my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have release variables in Azure Devops, not point in adding octopus to the mix if you only need release variables. They can be scoped to a release environment pretty much like the octopus ones.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#custom-variables

Example from my pipeline:
[image]

Each entry in that picture is tied to a single environment (like test and production are 2 different environments in your screenshot).

Comment: I had a look at azure-devops; in the link you provided it says "In the Pipeline Variables page, open the Scope drop-down list and select Release. I can't see any Scope dropdown anywhere … admiting I can see it and I manage to define every variable from my parms files in devops, what would be the next steps? how does it replace the values from my Cloud.xml parameter file for example?

Comment: I am clearly looking for the easiest way to manage this, which seemed to be octopus, if not can you provide any example please?

Comment: adding new tool to the pipeline is not "clearly the easiest way". I dont see how you derived that octopus is easier than adding variables to existing pipelines

Comment: Hm … maybe, could you tell me what are the steps after adding the variables are (still don't see where this Scope dropdown is but I guess that's a detail.)?

Comment: steps to do what?

Comment: in the release I define my variables and their values by environment, then how do I replace or inject those values in my parameters files (namely dev.xml and cloud.xml), anything else to do after that?

Comment: there is a replace token task that does that, you would need to add tokens to that file (pretty much like you would with octopus) and then it would pick up variables with the same name and replace them with values. after that you would deploy your app to SF

Comment: Alright I'll look into that, thanks. If you have any link detailing this, that would be nice, otherwise i'll try to find my way. Cheers

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens